# Django db not updating using Docker on production

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, cicd

Using `Django` and `Postgres` for my project, I can't  update my database on the production environment. I also tried running migration commands manually on the server, but it doesn't seem to work, as it always says the `migrations are already applied` and `no changes are detected`. When I check the migrations folder, I can see my new changes are specifically written, but the migrations aren't applied because I get a db error when I open the django admin panel; so I have no choice but to run `docker compose down -v` to delete the db and start fresh. (which is terrible cause I loose all my db records)

I believe it might be a cause of ignoring my migrations files, so the only things pushed to the server are regular files and `migrations/__init__.py`, so django can detect the app and apply the migrations.
Note that pushing all my migrations files to the server is not an option, because it's not efficient to go through all the changes I had in my local environment.
Is there any way I can solve this problem?

**`Dockerfile:`**

```py
FROM python:3.10-buster

RUN apt-get update

#RUN useradd -m myapp

RUN mkdir -p /home/myapp/app
WORKDIR /home/myapp/app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV PATH $PATH:/home/myapp/.local/bin

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "./entrypoint.sh"]
```

**`docker-compose.yml:`**

```py
version: "3.8"

networks:
  my_project_network:
    name: my_project_network

services:
  web:
    image: ${TAG_LATEST}
    container_name: ${API_CONTAINER_NAME}
    command: ["./entrypoint.sh"]
    volumes:
      - my_project_media_data:/home/myapp/app/media/
      - my_project_static_data:/home/myapp/app/static/
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    networks:
      - my_project_network
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: my_project-postgres
    volumes:
      - my_project_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_PORT=${POSTGRES_PORT}
    networks:
      - my_project_network
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: my_project-redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    networks:
      - my_project_network
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  my_project_media_data:
    name: my_project_media_data
  my_project_static_data:
    name: my_project_static_data
  my_project_postgres_data:
    name: my_project_postgres_data
```

**`entrypoint.sh:`**

```py
#!/bin/sh

echo "----------python makemigrations----------"
python manage.py makemigrations --noinput
python manage.py migrate --noinput

echo "----------python collectstatic----------"
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

echo "----------python runserver----------"
uvicorn config.asgi:application --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 & python manage.py rqworker default --with-scheduler

exec "$@"
```

**`gitlab-ci.yml:`**

```py
image: alpine:3

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

variables:
  TAG_LATEST: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:latest
  TAG_COMMIT: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA

build:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: build
  only:
    - main
  services:
    - name: docker:dind
      alias: thedockerhost
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://thedockerhost:2375/
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  before_script:
    - chmod +x deploy.sh
    - ./deploy.sh
  script:
    - docker build -t $TAG_COMMIT -t $TAG_LATEST .
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker push $TAG_COMMIT
    - docker push $TAG_LATEST

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - main
  before_script:
    - chmod +x deploy.sh
    - ./deploy.sh
  script:
    - chmod og= $ID_RSA
    - apk update && apk add openssh-client
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP -p $SERVER_SSH_PORT "sudo docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY"
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP -p $SERVER_SSH_PORT "sudo docker pull  $TAG_LATEST"
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP -p $SERVER_SSH_PORT "sudo docker container rm $API_CONTAINER_NAME -f || true"
    - scp -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -P $SERVER_SSH_PORT -r ./.env ./docker-compose.yml $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP:/home/dev/projects/my_project-service
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP -p $SERVER_SSH_PORT "cd /home/dev/projects/my_project-service && sudo docker compose up -d"
```

**`My db error:`**
[image]

Comment: What db error you are getting ?

Comment: @Ahtisham I updated my question with a screenshot of the db error I'm getting.